# Akka Streams: How to form inlets and outlets for a Graph using a Flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have some code that is similar to the following:

```
object Test extends App {
  val SomeComplicatedFlow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] =
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val input = builder.add(Balance[Int](1)) //Question 1) how to get rid of this input
      val buffer = Flow[Int].buffer(12, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      val balance = builder.add(Balance[Int](2))

      val flow1 = Flow[Int].map(_*2)
      val flow2 = Flow[Int].map(_*2)

      val zip = builder.add(ZipWith[Int, Int, Int]((left, right) => {
        left + right
      }))

      val flow3 = Flow[Int].map(_*2)

      input ~> buffer ~> balance.in
      balance.out(0) ~> flow1 ~> zip.in0
      balance.out(1) ~> flow2 ~> zip.in1
      zip.out ~> flow3

      FlowShape(input.in, flow3) //Question 2) how to make an outlet here
    })
}
```

Notice that I had to add a `Balance` called `input`, because I cannot retrieve an `Inlet` from the first `Buffer` of the `FlowShape` I want to create. Is there any other simpler way to solve this? Creating a `Balance` with 1 `Outlet` seems to be the wrong way to do this.

My second question is similar. I cannot retrieve an `Outlet` from `flow3`. The only way I know to solve this problem is to create yet another `Balance`, and expose its `Outlet` as the `Outlet` of the entire `FlowShape`. Any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Balance`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Balance.html) is a fan-out shape that emits to the first available output. Considering you are zipping the flows in the next step, what you need is a [`Broadcast`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Broadcast.html). It will fan-out to all outputs when all of them are available.

Also, the builder can add any of the shapes that are a `Graph`, this includes `Flow`. You don't have to use a custom shape for that.

The updated code:

```
object Test extends App {
  val SomeComplicatedFlow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] =
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val buffer = Flow[Int].buffer(12, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      val input = builder.add(buffer) 
      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

      val flow1 = Flow[Int].map(_*2)
      val flow2 = Flow[Int].map(_*2)

      val zip = builder.add(ZipWith[Int, Int, Int]((left, right) => {
        left + right
      }))

      val flow3 = builder.add(Flow[Int].map(_*2))

      input ~> broadcast.in
      broadcast.out(0) ~> flow1 ~> zip.in0
      broadcast.out(1) ~> flow2 ~> zip.in1
      zip.out ~> flow3.in

      FlowShape(input.in, flow3.out) 
    })
}
```